# Copying decrypted PDF file

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to write app which is searching for encrypted PDF files in specific folder. Then when it finds it, decrypt and create decrypted copy. However, I receive the error.

```py
import os
import PyPDF2

passwd=input("Password to decrypt: ")

for filename in os.listdir('pdfy\\'):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdfFile=open('pdfy\\' + filename,'rb')
        pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
        pdfWriter=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        if pdfReader.isEncrypted:
            pdfReader.decrypt(passwd)
            for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
                pageObj=pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
                pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

            pdfOutputFile=open('pdfy\\' + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_decrypted'+os.path.splitext(filename)[1],'wb')
            pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)
            pdfOutputFile.close()
    pdfFile.close()
```

Error message:

> PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: File has not been decrypted.

I have no idea what to do. Any suggestions please?

Comment: try this qpdf --password='' --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf

Comment: I would like to use PyPDF2 for this ;) The error is showing in the second loop for but I have no idea what is wrong here. When I will use pageObj=pdfReader.getPage(0) without loop there is no error...